# How do i make a specific vertical line with HTML CSS for "indent guide lines"

Tags: html, css, border

I'm currently making a portfolio website with the concept of making the site look like the code itself. Here's my code to see what im talking about:

```html
<div class="main-page">

  <pre><h1 class="doctype">1       &#60;<span style="color: #0087ca;">!DOCTYPE PORTFOLIO</span>&#62;<h1></h1></pre>


  <pre><p>2       &#60;html&#62;</p></pre>



  <pre><p>3           &#60;head&#62;</p></pre>
  <pre><p>4                &#60;title&#62; Alexander's Portfolio &#60;/title&#62;</p></pre>
  <pre><p>5           &#60;/head&#62;</p></pre>


  <pre><p>6           &#60;body&#62;</p></pre>

  <pre><p>7               &#60;p class = <span class="about-me">"About Me"</span> &#60;/p&#62;</p></pre>
  <pre><p>8               &#60;p class = <span class="about-me">"Hobbies"</span> &#60;/p&#62;</p></pre>
  <pre><p>9               &#60;p class = <span class="about-me">"Contact Me"</span> &#60;/p&#62;</p></pre>

  <pre><p>10          &#60;/body&#62;</p></pre>
  <pre><p>11      &#60;/html&#62;</p></pre>


</div>
```

Just like in code editors themselves I'm trying to create the indent guides (vertical lines) between the tags. I tried creating lines with putting the tags inside divs and just adding a border to the left but the paragraphs are messing up.

---

The sketch shows how I imagined it.

[image: html sketch]

Comment: what should it look like, can you sketch it?

Comment: uploaded an answer with the sketch

Answer (score 0):

I have created an example for you at the following [link](https://jsfiddle.net/cemfirat/t7ajycq8/2/). Maybe it will help you.

Code snippet from the link:

```css
.level {
   display: inline-block;
            min-width: 1vw;
 }

 .vertical_line {
    border-right: 1px solid black;
 }
```

```html
 <div>
   &nbsp<span class="line_nummber">2</span>
   <span class="level">&nbsp</span>

   <p class="inline_block">&#60;html&#62;</p>
 </div>
```

Alternatively, you can put this together in table - perhaps the disadvantage of responsive design.

If I were you, I would use a framework like:

- [Bootstrap CSS-Framework](https://getbootstrap.com/)
- [Materialize CSS](https://materializecss.com/)
- [Tailwind CSS Framework](https://tailwindcss.com/)